# iOS app free for specific university

Tags: ios, xcode

This is a bit of a tricky one. I am interested in seeing if there's a way to make an iOS free for a particular university. I know that I could create a discount code but the chances are that this would leak out and I would lose revenue from other universities. Is there any way around this e.g. checking their uni email or something?

Any help would be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the app into the `testflight` and grant access only to particular people. You can invite up to 1000 people to "test" your app, which should be sufficient. You invite them by email, which is quite convinient.

As for the rest, you could simply deploy an app to AppStore which you could charge for. Only selected students would gain a testflight invitation, and a free version of your app.

For more information, please look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).

Edit: The second option would be to put an app for free and through an `in-app purchase` unlock the premium version. People with university email would get their app unlocked for free - you would need an email database and somehow ensure only one is being used per app.

Comment: This is an interesting way. However, doesn't the TestFlight version expire after 30 days? Also, obviously, they would have to download TestFlight too which may not be something they want to do.

Comment: Yes it does, but you could perform "updates" once a month and force them to download a new app (which essentially would be the same one). This is not convenient and does require TestFlight app. See my edit for a second option.

Comment: App Review Guidelines specifically prohibit using TestFlight in that manner as "Apps may only use TestFlight to beta test apps intended for public distribution". As all TestFlight apps undergo review, the likelihood of the app being rejected is high.

Comment: Okay so this is going to be more challenging than I thought! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

If by 'discount code' you mean Apple's promo codes then leaking should not be an issue - I believe that they are one-use only. The problem would be that you would need to give them one code per user.

This is possibly not an option due to the cost, but you could distribute an Enterprise version of this app to the Uni: [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make the app free, but restrict some of the key functionality and unlock it with an in app purchase.  You could then ask for their email address (verify it is a valid address from the university in question), and send them a "unique" unlock code.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this in my mind would be to make the app free for all logins that end with "@myuni.edu" or something similar. Using promo codes have a cap and so does TestFlight.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Prateek do you have a user system in place at all?

Comment: No I do not :/ It is a very simple app which contains facts and information

Comment: @Prateek Well there are a ton of approaches to building a member system. If your app will be only in apple's eco-system for now and forever, then I'd recommend using CloudKit to store all your member data and simply check the email that's registered and do a verification on that email (click to verify email email).